# handling openid conusmer and provider in same page

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

hello i want to handle Zend framework version 1.11 openid library for login from conusmer to provider in one page without redirect users after enter identifier from consumer to provider do all things  in one action to avoid user from enter email in consumer and then enter email and password again in provider again

Answer (score 0):

So you want the user to be able to login with OpenID, without being redirected to their OpenID provider? If so, unfortunately that isn't possible. The whole point of OpenID is that it uses a third party login. However, if the user is already logged in to their provider's site, often they'll be redirected back to your app immediately so it would appear to work seamlessly.